# How does one implement a conditional poisson regression in R?

Tags: r, package, poisson

I am keen to implement a conditional (bivariate?) poisson regression in R to assess the change in rates of a variable (stratified by treatment condition) pre- / post- an intervention. Is anyone familiar with a package that runs this type of analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this ["gnm"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/gnm.pdf) package in R. It has a function of gnm() where you can specify you model formula, family=poisson(), offset, dataset and strata id in "eliminate". Please read it.